# CTE retrieving no rows is used in left join and where expression

Tags: sql, null, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have written an SQL query on Amazon Redshift and I face an issue with CTEs that return no rows.

The query is retrieving id's and timestamps from CTE No1 , and returns fields from CTEs No 2,3,4,5,6 after comparing timestamp field of the CTE No1 with those of CTE No2,3,4,5. To be more precise, below is a dummy code of my SQL query, I hope it is understandable. Please, do not give much attention to the LEAD() and LAG() functions the query problem is in essence a lot simpler that it might appear and is about when CTE's have 0 rows, but they are used in the where conditions of the final query, how to account for those cases .

```
with CTE1 AS 
(SELECT timestamp1, id
from table1
where ...
...
...)

, CTE2 as 
(select timestamp2, 
        id,  
        field1, 
        field2, 
        LAG(timestamp2,1) over partition by id order by timestamp2 as timestamp2_previous, 
        LEAD(timestamp2,1) over partition by id order by timestamp2 as timestamp2_next 
        from table2)

, CTE3 as 
(select timestamp3, 
        id, 
        field1, 
        field2, 
        LAG(timestamp3,1) over partition by id order by timestamp3 as timestamp3_previous, 
        LEAD(timestamp3,1) over partition by id order by timestamp3 as timestamp3_next 
       from table3)

, CTE4 as 
(select timestamp4, 
        id, 
        field1, 
        field2, 
        LAG(timestamp4,1) over partition by id order by timestamp4 as timestamp4_previous, 
        LEAD(timestamp4,1) over partition by id order by timestamp4 as timestamp4_next 
        from table4)

, CTE5 as 
(select timestamp5, 
        id, 
        field1, 
        field2, 
        LAG(timestamp5,1) over partition by id order by timestamp5 as timestamp5_previous, 
        LEAD(timestamp5,1) over partition by id order by timestamp5 as timestamp5_next 
        from table5)

, CTE6 as 
(select timestamp6, 
        id, 
        field1, 
        field2, 
        LAG(timestamp6,1) over partition by id order by timestamp6 as timestamp6_previous, 
        LEAD(timestamp6,1) over partition by id order by timestamp6 as timestamp6_next 
        from table6)

select cte1.id, 
       cte1.timestamp1, 
       case when cte1.timestamp1<cte2.timestamp2 and cte2.timestamp2_previous is null then cte2.field1 else cte2.field2, 
case when cte1.timestamp1<cte3.timestamp3 and cte3.timestamp3_previous is null then cte3.field1 else cte3.field2, 
case when cte1.timestamp1<cte4.timestamp4 and cte4.timestamp4_previous is null then cte4.field1 else cte4.field2, 
case when cte1.timestamp1<cte5.timestamp5 and cte5.timestamp5_previous is null then cte5.field1 else cte5.field2, 
case when cte1.timestamp1<cte6.timestamp6 and cte6.timestamp6_previous is null then cte6.field1 else cte6.field2

from cte1
left join cte2 on cte1.id=cte2.id
left join cte3 on cte1.id=cte3.id
left join cte4 on cte1.id=cte4.id
left join cte5 on cte1.id=cte5.id
left join cte6 on cte1.id=cte6.id
where 1 

and 

-- conditions for CTE2

( case when cte1.timestamp1 < cte2.timestamp2 and cte2.timestamp2_previous is null then 1=1
         else cte1.timestamp1 > cte2.timestamp2 end
and
        CASE
                WHEN cte2.timestamp2_next is not null THEN cte1.timestamp1 < cte2.timestamp2_next ELSE 1=1
        END
)

-- conditions for CTE3

( case when cte1.timestamp1 < cte3.timestamp3 and cte3.timestamp3_previous is null then 1=1
         else cte1.timestamp1 > cte3.timestamp3 end
and
        CASE
                WHEN cte3.timestamp3_next is not null THEN cte1.timestamp1 < cte3.timestamp3_next ELSE 1=1
        END
)

-- conditions for CTE4

( case when cte1.timestamp1 < cte4.timestamp4 and cte4.timestamp4_previous is null then 1=1
         else cte1.timestamp1 > cte4.timestamp4 end
and
        CASE
                WHEN cte4.timestamp4_next is not null THEN cte1.timestamp1 < cte4.timestamp4_next ELSE 1=1
        END
)


-- conditions for CTE5

( case when cte1.timestamp1 < cte5.timestamp5 and cte5.timestamp5_previous is null then 1=1
         else cte1.timestamp1 > cte5.timestamp5 end
and
        CASE
                WHEN cte5.timestamp5_next is not null THEN cte1.timestamp1 < cte5.timestamp5_next ELSE 1=1
        END
)


-- conditions for CTE6

( case when cte1.timestamp1 < cte6.timestamp6 and cte6.timestamp6_previous is null then 1=1
         else cte1.timestamp1 > cte6.timestamp6 end
and
        CASE
                WHEN cte6.timestamp6_next is not null THEN cte1.timestamp1 < cte6.timestamp6_next ELSE 1=1
        END
)
```

The problem is that some of the CTEs after the first, return no records for a specific id ( I tested my code for a specific id and CTE3 returns no rows for that ID).
In these cases, the where conditions in the end, which are all connected with AND, would evaluate the CTE that has not records in it, and return 0 rows ( because of the operation TRUE AND NULL), even though all the other CTE's have data for that id, and the query result should be retrieving data for them.

How can I retrieve the result for such cases, and get NULL in the resulting fields that refer to the CTE with now rows?

Comment: I'm having to make some assumptions here since your psuedo code doesn't contain the attributes that you write up in your paragraph like *"the where conditions in the end, which are all connected with AND,"* but... you can move your WHERE conditions in your final query to the ON clauses where those CTE's are LEFT JOIN'd into the query. This way those records are filtered BEFORE being joined.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JNevill what you proposed worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JNevill says, the answer is to move the where conditions to the join. To give you an idea how this works, your join between cte1 and cte2 becomes:
`ON cte1.id = cte2.id AND ((cte1.timestamp < cte2.timestamp and cte2.timestamp_previous IS NULL) OR cte1.timestamp > cte2.timestamp) AND (cte2.timestamp_next IS NULL OR cte1.timestamp < cte2.timestamp_next)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JNevill what you proposed worked!

Comment: If your problem is now solved, please mark the question as answered. This helps other users. You do this by clicking the check next to the answer.